# gcc no error with extra comma in array initializer

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, grammar, list-initialization

Here's an example:

```
int main () 
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3,};
}
```

Note the extra `,` after `3`. There is no warning even with `-Wall` and everything. I noticed this while reading some `coreutils` code that seemed to have a comma after the last element of an array. Is this UB, implementation-defined, or fine as is?

Comment: This has been allowed in C since the dawn of time (or well, since the ANSI/ISO standardization back in 1989 at least).

Answer (score 5):

According to the C (and C++) grammar such an initialization is correct.

From the C Standard

> 6.7.9 Initialization
> Syntax

```
1 initializer:
    assignment-expression
    { initializer-list }
    { initializer-list , }
//...
```

You may initialize such a way even scalar objects as for example

```
int x = { 10, };
```

Pay attention to that in C23 you may initialize objects (including variable length arrays) with empty braces as for example

```
int x = {};
```

or

```
int n = 4;
int a[n] = {};
```

Comment: What is the use for the last three examples?

Comment: @user129393192 I provided the  last examples provided that your compiler supports the C23 standard.

Comment: Yes, but what is the use case for the scalar object initialization and also the empty brackets?

Comment: @user129393192 Such an object is initialized the same way as an object with static storage duration. For example objects of arithmetic types are zero-initialized.

Comment: So then why would `int x = {};` and `int x = {10,};` ever be useful if they are equivalent to `int x = 0;` and `int x = 10;`?

Comment: @user129393192 Using braces makes the initialization unified. Of course there is no great sense to write int x = { 10, }; instead of int x = { 10 };  or int x = 10;

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean. I don’t see the use case, unless I am missing something. Are you saying they’re allowing it just because they can?

Comment: @user129393192 The trailing comma makes the life of programmers more easy because it will not be an error if you will type it. And you are allowed to initialize objects of scalar and compound types in the similar manner.

Comment: So there is no real use case to int x = 10 vs int x = { 10 } ? When you say uniformity, you mean similar manner of initialization?

Comment: @user129393192 It can be more flexible for example when the compiler supports C23 where there is introduced type specifier typeof. For example typeof( a ) x = { 1 }; If a is an array or a scalar object such a declaration will be valid.

Comment: Understood. That is more complex C style than I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

Fine as is. The C standard permits it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only for declarations but also for changes, you can replace `;` with `,` (struct in the example below) **last three lines**:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
} test;

int main(void)
{
    test hi = (test) {
        .a = 0,
        .b = 1,
        .c = 'a',
    };

    hi.a = 6,
    hi.b = 9,
    hi.c = 'r';
}
```

Comment: Why is this useful?